# How to detect div don't have child class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code like the following:-

```js
if($('.container').has(':not(.classB)')){
  //$(this).addClass('added'); - this code didnt work,i dont know why @@
  $('.container').addClass('added');
}
//if($('.container').find('.classB').length != 0)
```

```css
.added .classA{background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="classA">AA</div>
    <div class="classB">BB</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="classA">AA</div>
</div>
```

I have tried some ways to detect div don't have classB but it doesn't work. Here is both div affected (added new class). This should be only working with div class 'containter' don't have classB in it (2nd div).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just test for the opposite of `.hasClass` along with `children()`?

Also, your current CSS selector of: `.added .classA` would only affect elements with a class of `classA` that are descendants of elements that have class `added`, which is none of your elements.

```js
// Loop through the containers
$('.container').each(function(){
 
  // If the current container doesn't have any children that use classB...
  if(!$(this).children().hasClass('classB')){
    // Add the added calss to the child in question
    $(this).children().addClass('added');
  }

});
```

```css
.added {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="classA">AA</div>
  <div class="classB">BB</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="classA">AA</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following might work :

```
$('.container').each(function(index) {
    // if containing at least one descendant with classB
    if( $(this).find('.classB').length > 0 ) {
        console.log('class B found in container n°'+ index);
        // do your stuff..
    }
    // if not containing any descendants with classB
    if( $(this).find('.classB').length == 0 ) {
        console.log('class B NOT found in container n°'+ index);
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

Basically, it will run through all your containers, select all descendants with classB inside each container, and we use length to check if it managed to find some or not.

*Note that .find() will go looking for classB in every descendants ( more than 1 level deep), if you want to stop looking at level 1, use .children() instead.*

Hope I could help :)

Comment: This is a good idea ! Thanks :)
P/s: you're missing a `)` at the end code :)

Comment: Woops, it's damn hard to write code without syntax coloring :p I will fix it.

Comment: And i need it should be **not find** (opposite of `find()` )

Comment: Actually, find() is returning a set of elements, not a boolean. The condition here is on length > 0, so the contrary is : ...find('.classB').length == 0

Answer (score 0):

You could go the other way, and start with any matching children

```js
$('.classB').parent('.container').addClass('added');
```

```css
.added { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="classA">AA</div>
    <div class="classB">BB</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="classA">AA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have many DIV similar this so i need to detect which DIV dont have .classB for my purpose. I can do this by myself with which DIV have .classB

Comment: `$('.classB').parent('.container')` would select all containers that have a `.classB` element, it just starts in the other end.